# Vue devtools can't open component on editor with macbook m1

Tags: vue.js, apple-m1, vue-devtools

I installed PhpStorm-2022.3-aarch64.dmg. Downloaded on official website JetBrains.

I click button "Open in editor" on vue devtools.

Exception

```
2022-12-10 22:33:20.212 phpstorm[5378:39479] allVms required 1.8*,1.8+
2022-12-10 22:33:20.215 phpstorm[5378:39485] Cannot load JVM bundle: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3585 "dlopen_preflight(/Applications/PhpStorm.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib) => false, tried: '/Applications/PhpStorm.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Applications/PhpStorm.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib' (no such file), '/Applications/PhpStorm.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle doesn’t contain a version for the current architecture., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try installing a universal version of the bundle., NSFilePath=/Applications/PhpStorm.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib, NSDebugDescription=dlopen_preflight(/Applications/PhpStorm.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib) => false, tried: '/Applications/PhpStorm.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Applications/PhpStorm.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib' (no such file), '/Applications/PhpStorm.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), NSBundlePath=/Applications/PhpStorm.app/Contents/jbr, NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “JBR-17.0.5+1-653.14-jcef 17.0.5” couldn’t be loaded because it doesn’t contain a version for the current architecture.}

Could not open ContactCard.vue in the editor.
The editor process exited with an error: (code 255).

To specify an editor, specify the EDITOR env variable or add "editor" field to your Vue project config.
```

I try .env variable
`EDITOR="phpstorm"` and `EDITOR="~/Application/PhpStorm.app/Contents/MacOS/phpstorm"`, and i don't use it at all.

I try install intel version - the result is the same.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason. I need to install the ARM version of Node.js. The problem was resolved when I installed [Node.js v16.14 of ARM]

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/devtools/issues/1668